# Did lower tier angels know that God had left heaven?

Tags: supernatural

In season 4x01, Castiel tells Dean that it was God who commanded that he be rescued from hell. We know that God had left heaven a long time ago; So were lower tier angels like Castiel under the impression that God was still in heaven, or were they aware - and in this instance was Castiel possibly referring to instructions in the prophecy?

Comment: I can't properly source this right now, but my impression was that all angels knew God had left quite a long time ago, hence Castiel's surprise when God commanded him to pull Dean out of hell. No spoilers, but in later seasons this is more apparent.

Comment: Not sure about *Supernatural's* lore, but IIRC in biblical lore, only the Archangels were actually allowed in the presence of God.  Lower tier angels, like Castiel, would have been operating on orders from higher ranking angels who told him "God said to do this."  Supernatural isn't 100% the same as biblical lore, but it's remarkably close from what I've seen.

Comment: @Loki I'm up do date with supernatural, but watching clips from earlier seasons, it seems Castiel thought God was around. Does Castiel mention being surprised when 'God' commanded him to pull Dean out of hell?

Comment: @Logan545 Hmm, you have a point there. It's actually been almost 9 years since I last watched season 4 :)